# How do I read the content of a web response?

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

How do I read the content of a web response? I tried using FiddlerCore to inspect the respones. It is possible to isolate the correct request and response. But I am only able to get the header of the file being sent. I need the content. but it is always empty in the AfterSessionComplete-method. There does seems to be some binary data in the OnReadResponseBuffer-method. Maybe it is gzipped as indicated in the header? Any ideas of how to read the content of a response. Ideas not using fiddler are welcome too.

```
void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Fiddler.Session oSession)
{
    listBox1.Invoke(new UpdateUI(() =>
    {
        if (oSession.PathAndQuery.Contains("mobj.php"))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("   " + oSession.fullUrl);
            byte[] body = oSession.ResponseBody;
            string body_string = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body); // always empty
        }
    }));
}

static void FiddlerApplication_OnReadResponseBuffer(object sender, RawReadEventArgs e)
{
    string bla = "";

    if (e.sessionOwner.fullUrl.Contains("mobj.php"))
        bla = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.arrDataBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do it with FiddlerCore?  You could just use System.Net.Http.HttpClient, and it would be a lot simpler.

Comment: "Ideas not using fiddler are welcome too" - if you are using Fiddler to change actual requests/responses I'm not sure how not using its objects would help. But if you are doing general web scraping it regular classes are fine. Please clarify if you need to look at HTTP traffic or just make sure particular request gets particular response (`WebClient` class is on of easy ways to do so).

Comment: The website is dynamically generated. The request I want to look at is loaded after a bunch of javascript code generates the url. That's why I chose to use a WebBrowser control and then just add fiddler as a listener to it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `UTF8.GetString()` makes the faulty assumption that the content is raw UTF-8 bytes; it may well be any other encoding.

Instead, you should be using the `oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString()` method. Now, keep in mind that this only returns a string if the response actually contained a body. If it was, for instance, a `HTTP/304` response (meaning "Reuse the version from your cache") there will be no body bytes. However, you'd see that `OnReadResponseBuffer` still fires, since the HTTP/304 header block would be passed through that function.